# Get the value of the "src" attribute

Tags: 8

I am having hard time with getting the value of YouTube video thumbnail URL, in order to use it as background image in a template file.

I created a video content type and added a remote video field (*field_url_vid2*). The output format is *thumbnail*.

`{{content.field_url_vid2}}` gives the full HTML markup, but I just want the value of the *src* attribute.

Answer (score 1):

To get the YouTube video thumbnail URL in twig!
Try with:

```
{{ file_url(content.field_url_vid2.0['#media'].thumbnail.0.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Comment: Hi 
I just got a "/" as result. 
I am inserting this in node--video.html.twig

Comment: In kint content.field_url_vid2.0['#media'].thumbnail.0.entity.uri.value NULL

Comment: use twig_vardumper module and do `{{ dump(content.field_url_vid2.0['#media']) }}` see if exist and then `{{ dump(content.field_url_vid2.0['#media'].thumbnail.0.entity) }}` i have tested this it works for me

Comment: Unfortunately it does not even appear in the tree...maybe it is related to the preprocess functions introduced in theme ? I did not do it myself. So i need to investigate more

Comment: Maybe, do you use a custom theme ? i have tested it with default theme and bootstarp theme it works, and i used the **remote video** with it's default config, take a look if your thumbnail disabled in the **manage display** or something